# python function with Django

Tags: javascript, python, html, django

Hey guys I have a problem,

I have next function in my views.py:

```
@userRegistered
def getSyncGit(request, section):
       print 'POTATOE' #(<-debug print)
       cmd =  '. script.sh 1'
       p = sp.Popen(['/bin/bash', '-c', cmd], stdout=sp.PIPE, stderr=sp.PIPE)
       result = p.wait()
       return HttpResponseRedirect(getURL(request.LANGUAGE_CODE, '/assistant/configuration/project/list/'))
```

At the urls.py:

```
from .views import getSyncGit
url(r'^/project/sync/$', getSyncGit, {'section':'configuracion'}, name='pgetSyncGit'),
```

And in my template:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function sendSyncProject()
        {
        $.ajax({url: "{% url 'pgetSyncGit' %}", success: function(result){
            alert('cool');
            }});
        }
</script>
<td>
    <input id="butSendSyncProject" type="button" name="butSendSyncProject" style="margin-left:1px;" value="{% trans 'Sinc' %}" onclick="sendSyncProject()" />
</td>
<td>
    <a href = "{% url 'pgetSyncGit' %}"> asdasdasdasdasddas </a>
</td>
```

When I call to action with button, I can see thealert message, but the `getSyncGit` function is not executed.
When I call to action with url href, it redirects me to the url "/project/sync/", but the function neither executes....

Comment: what do you see that makes you believe the function view isn't executed? Any error?

Comment: there is no error. 
it seems like the function is not called.

Answer (score 0):

Try to change your script to a script that writes a line into a file like "`echo 'test' > tmp.txt`" and tell us if `tmp.txt` is being created or not

Comment: hi @OliverPons I've answered to this post below in a new post

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your answer @Oliver

I've tried what you've said and it doesn't work.

I've tried the following:
At the urls.py:
from .views import editDeProject

```
url(r'^/project/edit/0', editDeProject, {'section':'configuracion'}, name='pgetSyncGit'),
```

And now i have next function in my views.py:

```
def editDeProject(request, id, section):
        """Page Edit of DB de_project"""
        errorTable = ''
        form = None
        if id == 0:
                getSyncGit(request,id,section)
        else:
                try:
                        table = DeProject.objects.get(codProject=id)
                        if request.method == 'POST':
```

Using this method it works, it prints POTATOE and it generates file.txt, however I'm forcing url.py to take id 0 as an input.

therefore I believe the problem is when the (r'^/project/sync/(?P.*)/' gets generated